# "Maintenance mode" message is shown when the site isn't in maintenance

Tags: cron, maintenance-mode

I get the "Operating in maintenance mode. Go online." message and the Drupal 7 site isn't in maintenance mode.

The message doesn't appears all the time; sometimes it goes away when I refresh the page. I cleared cache; I tested, and it is most certainly not in maintenance mode.

I checked Drupal error reports, and I get this one. (I don't know whether it's related.)

> TIPO  acceso denegado
> FECHA Martes, 14 May, 2013 - 01:11
> USUARIO   Anónimo (-)
> UBICACIÓN http://www.liga.net/cron.php
> REFERENTE
> MENSAJE   frontpage
> SEVERIDAD advertencia
> NOMBRE DE LA MÁQUINA  xx.xxx.xx.xxx

Sometimes in a complete random way, as an anonymous users, it appears the *Site offline* page. When I reload the page it´s up again.

Comment: In D7, cron.php requires an access key that you can find in admin/reports/status. If it's not present, you'll get a 403.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search variable table in database. Variable named maintenance_mode should be there, and should be a serialized representation of false (or numerical 0). If it's not, your site will have a problem.
If this appeared after upgrade, re-running update.php might help

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That variable it´s not there, and after the upgrade its still not there. May I create it manually? It seems I just have to create it under name, and put a zero (0) in value slot. Is that correct? Thanks again!

Comment: `b:0` for false and `b:1` for true, not just a number or string. Yes, do create it manually.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment! 
I´ve tried the update script one last time before messing manually with the database (scary thing!), and now there´s a maintenance_mode. But its value is "[BLOB - 4 B]" ??

Comment: Your answer lead me to some errors in update.php (thanks for the tip!!). As that´s somewhat out of topic, I´m opening a new question (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73092/how-to-solve-these-errors-after-running-update-php) to try to get to the error. 
I´m also setting this as the correct answer because it seems that the maintenance error is gone (yay!).
THANKS MOLOT!

Comment: 4 bytes of blob are: b:0 and `\0` to terminate it as null terminated string.

Comment: Thanks! So, it seems that´s just as it should be. Maybe that´s why I don´t get that message anymore. Thank you!!