# Maintenance page being rendered as an entire page load after the main page load

Tags: 7, theming, debugging, maintenance-mode

I've noticed that I've got a maintenance page being rendered in its entire HTML markup format after my pages. The site is *not* in maintenance mode, and this is not intentional behaviour. I'm trying to debug, but even as a reasonably experienced Drupal developer I still don't understand all the mechanisms at work here. Guidance on that would be welcomed.

I had been using the module CDN, to experiment with integrating a CDN. That was using that area at the bottom of the page, but when I disabled it, and uninstalled it, it has not stopped the problem.

I then enabled Theme developer 7.x-1.x-dev just to help me see what was going on, and the maintenance page render has stopped appearing. I then disabled Theme developer again and it has returned. Does this help anyone to suggest something?

```
</body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>

[...]

</head>
<body class="maintenance-page in-maintenance no-sidebars">
  <div id="page">
    <div id="header">
```

This also displays on my admin theme. Does this mean it is not something to do with my custom theme? Is there anything in particular that I could look or has anyone seen this behaviour before?

[image: page rendering twice]

Comment: Hey hey, thing is, debugging needs to be done by you. Otherwise this question simply is too broad to answer. We don't know your site, your setup, your server, your custom code etc.. So it can basically be everything. Please come back when you found the root of your problem and still don't know how to solve it. Good luck!

Comment: I'm going to try and see if it's a problem with maintenance mode firstly: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72944/drupal-7-maintenance-mode-message-when-the-site-is-not-in-maintenance-yes-i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still waiting to see an answer to [the question of what causes maintenance mode to be displaying messages](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269974/what-makes-a-maintenance-mode-message-display-when-a-site-is-not-in-maintenance). So I don't know specifically whether the recoverable fatal error ([this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap/issues/2986847)) being thrown by the buggy 7.x-2.4 version of XML Sitemap module was what caused the avoidance of a general WSOD/ crash and yet a display of an odd maintenance mode message.

I had not noticed they'd released 7.x-2.5 and so I've updated that which has stopped the behaviour altogether. Happy days :)

Answer (score 0):

Chiming in late here, but I came across this yesterday after having the same problem. In my case, there was a stray call to dpm() in hook_preprocess_field_collection_item(); The Devel module was disabled in production, so when the page hit the dpm() call, everything broke. I don't know why this caused the page to go into maintenance mode, but removing the Devel debugging function fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever find the reason?
I am having the same problem right now and cant find why or how

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73191467/drupal-7-response-with-two-sets-of-html-a-normal-followed-by-an-in-maintenance

Comment: tbh I can't remember, sorry. Check the logs. Check the /var/sys logs if nothing is obvious check all the logs! You'll have to try and find a thread somewhere and start pulling. I hope you find it!